# How Do I Calculate the Average of Numbers Submitted to an Input Field?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code:

Grade Average

function dosomething




{




  var i = Number;





 var numbers = new Array{a,b,c};




        numbers[0] = a;




        numbers[1] = b;




        numbers[2] = c;





 var total=0;





    for (i=0; i

```
</head>

<body>
 <p id= "functionOutput"></p>

<input type="text" id="input" />

<input type= "button" id="enter" onclick="dosomething(input.value)" 
value="Calculate" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: The formatting seems to have come out a bit strange, too.

Comment: I edited the whitespace in your code but man there are some serious issues here.

Comment: Updating your question to make it easier to help would be a good start and then array.reduce might be worth looking at. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you need to do two things:

1. Collect numerical value of input when button is pressed and store in an array
2. Calculate average of array's content

#### 1. Collect/Store Numerical Value of Input

```
var calculate_btn = document.getElementById('enter'),
    input_field = document.getElementById('input'),
    all_values = [];

// store input value to array when button is clicked
calculate_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var input_value = parseFloat( input_field.value );

  // ensure it is a number
  if( isNaN( input_value ) ) return;

  all_values.push( input_value );
});
```

#### 2. Calculate Average of Array's Content

```
function get_input_value_average(){

  // calculate new average
  var total = 0,
      average;

  all_values.forEach( function( entry ){
    total += entry;
  });

  average = total / all_values.length;
  return average;
}
```

#### Pulling it All Together

Put this script tag just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>

  var calculate_btn = document.getElementById('enter'),
      input_field = document.getElementById('input'),
      all_values = [];

  // store input value to array when button is clicked
  calculate_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var input_value = parseFloat( input_field.value );

    // ensure it is a number
    if( isNaN( input_value ) ) return;

    all_values.push( input_value );

    var input_average = get_input_value_average();

    alert( 'average: ' + input_average + ' | entries: ' + all_values.join( ', ' ) );
  });

  function get_input_value_average(){

    // calculate new average
    var total = 0,
        average;

    all_values.forEach( function( entry ){
      total += entry;
    });

    average = total / all_values.length;
    return average;
  }
</script>
```

That should do it.